# Does "X was sick the past two weeks" mean X is still sick?

Tags: grammar, tenses

How would I say I was sick for two weeks ***before*** now (because *now* I am not sick anymore)? Would it be like this:

> I was sick the past two weeks.

I ask this because from what I have found ‘the past’ includes *now* because I know we can say ‘I’ve been sick the past two weeks,’ which would mean that I am still sick. I’m confused!

Comment: The past tense is different than past perfect tense.

Comment: This is a good occasion to keep the prepositions around so it's clear how everything functions. I would say "I was sick for the last two weeks". Adding "But now I'm OK" is in order, too. You can't expect minimal grunts to get all the information across.

Comment: It says little about your current condition.  You could still be sick, you could be recovering, or you could be completely recovered.

Answer (score 1):

> I was sick the past two weeks.

is the correct way. The use of the [past](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html) tense *was* indicates that this refers entirely to the past, the present time is not included. *have been* would be the [present perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html) tense, which includes the current time.

Answer (score 0):

"in the past two weeks" means the TIME PERIOD IS NOT FINISHED, then the Present Perfect is the right tense to be used. It can also be replaced by "lately". 
. I have worked a lot in the past two weeks.

"last week" is in the past, therefore we use the Simple Past.
. I worked a lot last week.  (time is over)
. She canceled all her appointments yesterday because her son has been ill in the past months.

Hope it helps.